# Zend Db Table Abstract Manipulate select()

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

is there any chance to set a where statement on any select() request regarding a Zend Db Table Abstract Object?

*Example: 
We have 2 roles, 1 role 'admin' which is allowed to see all products and 1 role 'supplier' which is allowed to see only their own products.*

I don't want to check the role and set the where statement for the Zend Db Table Abstract Object in every ActionController. Is there any chance to do this in the Zend Db Table Abstract?

```
class ProductsModel extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

protected $_name = 'artikel';
protected $_primary = 'ID';
protected $_where = ('supplier = ?', $this->_auth->Role ); # SOMETHING LIKE THAT ??

}
```

Thanks!
M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two definitions in ZF: Model and Table. You should not substitute them. The model describes abstract layer between Controller and Table. The model may work with Table by means of Mapper where you can implement all business logic (where clauses, order, limit and so on).
It all are included into standart ZF example template.